# R Help - na.approx similar to SuperTrend in Excel

Tags: r, interpolation, trend

```
Raw Data    na.approx   desired result
1               1             1
NA              3             4
5               5             5
6               6             6
7               7             7
NA              8             4
NA              9             7
10             10            10
13             11            13
14             12            14
```

By default, i believe `na.approx` in `R` will interpolate `NA` between two known values; one before and another after `NA` (the result will be seen as column "na.approx" above). Is there a way I can change this function to interpolate based on next two known values? for eg, first `N`A to be interpolated using 5 and 6.... but not 1 and 5.

Comment: Why is desired result for first `NA` is `4`, if it should be between `5` and `6`?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is similar to TREND/SuperTREND function in excel. it went down by -1 (from 6 to 5) so i want to apply the same logic for NAs (5 to 4 by subtracting 1)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an exact equivalent to what you want to do, but you can achieve similar results the following way:

```
> data <- c(1, NA, 5,6,7,NA,NA,10,13,14)
> ind <- which(is.na(data))
> sapply(rev(ind), function(i) data[i] <<- data[i + 1] - 1)
> data
 [1]  1  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 13 14
```